# Trying to build a content locker using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook

I am very new to jQuery and not entirely sure what I'm doing. Will try my best to explain the problem I'm facing.

I'm trying to lock some content on a landing page until a user shares the link using FB, Twitter, LinkedIN or G+. The first version of the script I wrote (which worked fine) ran like this:

```
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 ...
 $(document).ready(function()
  {
   $('.class').click(clearroadblock());
   buildroadblock();
  }
 </script>

 <style>
 .class
  {
   [css stuff]
  }
 </style>
</head>

<body>
 <div id="something">
  <ul>
   <li> <a href="link1" target="blank" class="class">Link1</a> </li>
   <li> <a href="link2" target="blank" class="class">Link2</a> </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</body>
```

The problem I'm now facing is changing out this code to replace the list elements with social share buttons. As they are no longer under `.class`, but classes like `fb-share-button` and `twitter-share-button`. Please help me understand what I need to modify to accommodate this? PS: This is not a Wordpress site.

```
function clearroadblock()
{
    $('#roadblockdiv').css('display', 'none');
    $('#roadblockBkg').css('display','none');
}
```

This is the way I'm clearing the overlay once a click is detected, BTW.

Can I wrap the social buttons in divs, assign them IDs and use those IDs to trigger the click like below?

```
<div id="Button">
 <a href="link" class"twitter-share-button">Tweet</a>
</div>

$('#Button').click(clearroadblock());
```

Comment: What do you mean by "lock the content"? Do you mean fix it to the middle of the page or something, like an overlay?

Comment: @JonathanBrooks Yes, exactly. That part is working alright, and I didn't include it in this snippet. The problem is that the overlay isn't disappearing when someone clicks on the social share buttons. It does disappear if it's a plain link.

Comment: FYI: At least for Facebook, you are _not allowed_ to reward users for sharing, or keep content from them until they shared.

Comment: @CBroe Really?? I thought social lockers are not an issue! Thanks so much, will look into this immediately.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#properuse, 4.5: _“Only incentivize a person to log into your app, enter a promotion on your app’s Page, or check-in at a place. Don’t incentivize other actions.”_

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple classes on an element by separating them with a space. Try the following:

```
class="class fb-share-button"
```

Your jquery will still work off the "class"  class. I would recommend you change this name to something more meaningful though. Your css can target the "class"  for general styles, but you can also target fb and twitter separately.

---

## Update

I decided to create a quick [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gwbno6qa/2/) for this.

Some of the styles etc won't be the same as what you're doing, but the problem is resolved. I've created a div with id main that contains the content that you want to hide. There's an absolutely positioned div over the top of this, this is the roadblock. The javascript is showing the roadblock (assuming that's what you wanted to do with `buildroadblock()`).

On click of a link in the ul with id socialMedia we call `clearroadblock`. Notice the lack of parenthesis. This hides the roadblock.

This isn't a great way of preventing someone from seeing information, you might want to think about pulling the content down from the server when the action is performed, however, I think this answers your question.

Comment: I tried this. It still isn't working, though. Is there a problem in the way I'm making the overlay disappear?